# Java regex skip match

Tags: java, regex, pcre

I need to capture all `#` characters in the text except those that are surrounded by `#[ ... #]`. 
I wrote the PCRE version ([online example](https://regex101.com/r/cI6eD4/2)) which works great but Java doesn't support (*SKIP)(*FAIL).

```
 #\[.*#\](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|#
```

Is there an Java equivalent of this regex? Thanks.

Comment: Give an example of a string you want to match.

Comment: @jamesjelo4kul: There is a link in my question. I added some text to it for better imagination.

Comment: @anubhava: Just capture, Then I can replace it in Java...

Comment: @StefanH - What do you want to replace the #s with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses a little trick to match the `#`s you don't want first and then match the rest in a capture group:

`#\[.*?#\]|(#+)`

https://regex101.com/r/sU1kR2/1

You will need to extract the first capture group to get the desired `#`s.

If you want to capture each individual `#` not part of or in the custom brackets, you can drop the `+` from the capture group as follows:

`#\[.*?#\]|(#)`

Also, if you can have text like `##[text]#`, then you might need a lookaround as follows:

`#\[.*?#\]|(#(?!\[))`

If you can use `\K` (but I don't think you can in Java), it is even simpler with the following because then you don't have to worry about capture groups:

`#\[.*?#\]\K|#`

Comment: The last solution is very nice but I can't use `\K` in Java. The first one works, thanks.

Comment: How is it failing if the brackets aren't properly formed?  The legal expression would be `#[This one is # ok#]`.

Comment: @MaxZoom - Okay, but see what happens when I property form the closing bracket: https://regex101.com/r/sU1kR2/3.

Comment: OK I see, the OP post text has changed since I looked at it.